# Changing the text on action bar custom view

Tags: android, custom-component, android-actionbar-compat

I implemented custom actionBar in my Project. It has two Textview I want to change the text Programatically  how to do that. I tried the following code but there is no change in my action bar

```
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbarlayout, null);
    mSiteName= ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sitenameastitle));

    mSiteName.setText("helloooo");

    this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: You should do some searching first before asking a question, but just for a first push i have given a code below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
public void ActivityName(String name)
{
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View activityName = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_title_view, null);

    ((TextView) activityName.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title)).setText(name);

    Typeface robotoBoldCondensedItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/bisque.ttf");

    ((TextView) activityName.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title)).setTypeface(robotoBoldCondensedItalic);

    actionBar.setCustomView(activityName);
}
```